# How can you nest StreamBuilders in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, stream, google-cloud-firestore

I have 2 Streams that I need to combine to build a widget, but unlike other questions I have seen I need to nest my streams.

I have a stream that gets a collection of documents from Firestore, and a stream that depends on data from the first to get a subcollection of documents. I would like to combine these into one stream, but they need to be nested since each document has its own subcollection of documents.

Stream 1 (Gets a collection of habits from FireStore):

```
Stream<List> getHabits(){
  final Stream<QuerySnapshot> documents = Firestore.instance
    .collection("users")
    .document('VtL1sxOoCOdJaOTT87IbMRwBe282')
    .collection("habits")
    .snapshots();

  Stream<List> data = documents.map((doc) {
    List data;
    final documents = doc.documents;
    ///Maybe this would work to get history of each doc? 
    for(int i = 0; i < documents.length; i++){
      ///not sure what to do
      getHistory(documents[i].documentID, DateTime.utc(2019,7,7), DateTime.now());
    }

    data = documents.map((documentSnapshot) => documentSnapshot).toList();

    return data;
  });

  return data;
}
```

Stream 2 (Called in Stream 1, Takes `DocumentID` as a parameter, gets sub-collection of documents):

```
Stream<List> getHistory(String id, DateTime start, DateTime end) async* {
  await for (QuerySnapshot querySnapshot in Firestore.instance
    .collection("users")
    .document('VtL1sxOoCOdJaOTT87IbMRwBe282')
    .collection("habits")
    .document(id)
    .collection("history")
    .where('day', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: start)
    .where('day', isLessThanOrEqualTo: end)
    .snapshots()) {

      List history;
      final documents = querySnapshot.documents;
      
      history = documents.map((documentSnapshot) => documentSnapshot).toList();

      yield history;
    }
}
```

How can I combine these streams in a nested format into one stream to be used with `StreamBuilder` in Flutter?

### Edit

I am not sure if I am working in the right direction or not but I have tried to implement the solution from spenster and this is what I have at the moment in addition to the functions above.

```
StreamBuilder<List>(
  stream: getHabits(),
  initialData: [],
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    List<UserHabit> habits = [];
    List<Widget> test = List.generate(snapshot.data.length, (index){
      List<History> history = [];
      DocumentSnapshot doc = snapshot.data[index];
      return StreamBuilder(
        stream: getHistory(doc.documentID, DateTime.utc(2019,7,7), DateTime.now()),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError)
            return new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.waiting: return new Text('Loading...');
            default:
              if(!snapshot.data.isEmpty){ //history collection exists
                for(int i = 0; i < snapshot.data.length; i++){
                  //add to history
                  history.add(History(
                    day: snapshot.data[i]['day'].toDate(), 
                    dateCompleted: snapshot.data[i]['dateCompleted'].toDate(), 
                    morning: snapshot.data[i]['morning'],
                    afternoon: snapshot.data[i]['afternoon'],
                    evening: snapshot.data[i]['evening'],
                    anytime: snapshot.data[i]['anytime'],
                  ));
                }
              }
              habits.add(UserHabit(
                name: doc['habit'],
                color: doc['color'],
                icon: doc['icon'],
                repeat: doc['repeat'],
                daily: doc['daily'],
                weekly: doc['weekly'],
                monthly: doc['monthly'],
                time: doc['time'],
                history: history,
              ));
              print(habits); //returns each iteration of assembling the list
              return Text("i dont want to return anything");
          }
        },
      );
      }
    );
    print(habits); //returns empty list before anything is added
    return Column(
      children: test,
    );

  },
),
```

The Class for UserHabits and History can be shared, but they are just basic classes that assign types and allow easy access.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have done something similar simply using nested `StreamBuilders`. Depending on how you want your `Widget`s organized, you can create streams within the outer `StreamBuilder`. Based on your clarifying comments, this is one possibility:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  var habits = Firestore.instance
    .collection("users")
    .document('VtL1sxOoCOdJaOTT87IbMRwBe282')
    .collection("habits")
    .snapshots();

  return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
    stream: habits,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {

      if (!snapshot.hasData)
        return Text("Loading habits...");

      return ListView(children: snapshot.data.documents.map((document) {

        var query = Firestore.instance
          .collection("users")
          .document('VtL1sxOoCOdJaOTT87IbMRwBe282')
          .collection("habits")
          .document(document.documentID)
          .collection("history")
          .where('day', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: start)
          .where('day', isLessThanOrEqualTo: end)
          .snapshots();

        return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream: query,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {

            if (!snapshot.hasData) return Text("Loading...");

            // right here is where you need to put the widget that you
            // want to create for the history entries in snapshot.data...
            return Container();
          },
        );
      }).toList());
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll give it a shot and if it works I will mark your answer as correct! I appreciate the time you took to answer it!

Comment: Just out of curiosity is there any way I can just not return anything in `getHistory` `StreamBuilder`? I need to use a list of `history` data to see if things were completed or not, but I am only building one widget per item in `getHabits()`

Comment: I am also getting the following error `The element type 'Set<StreamBuilder<List>>' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'.`

Comment: If you only want one document from your history colection, then you can use Firestore to select it (say using .limit(1) on your query), then build just a single widget. That should also incidentally eliminate the other error you're seeing too. I'll see if I can update the answer...

Comment: Here I am going to update the question so you can see what I mean. I made some progress but I cannot access a variable that I modified in the second streambuilder outside of it. There is one stream that gets the habits, then the other gets the history for each habit. For the application I am working on I need to check to see say how many times something was completed in the last week before showing a widget. There is only one widget being returned per habit, but the widget requires all the history to assemble it if that makes sense.

Comment: If you have a chance please check my update so you can better understand my intentions. If I could use habits at the second print location I think this solution would work but I can't because StreamBuilder is asynchronous. Which is why I wanted to nest the streams before using StreamBuilder but I wasn't sure if that was possible.

Comment: Please see my update. All you have left to do there is create your widget based on the various history entries retrieved in the second `StreamBuilder`.

Comment: I think I managed to get this method to work but I feel like there should be a way to nest streams without needed to nest streambuilders. Or firebase should make it easier to access sub-documents haha. Thank you so much for your time, I will mark this correct! Been working on this one dilemma for about a week.

Answer (score 1):

Try merging your streams with something like `Observable.zip2(stream1,stream2,zipper)` or  `Observable.combineLatest2(streamA, streamB, combiner)`.

For more info, check this [post](https://www.burkharts.net/apps/blog/rxdart-magical-transformations-of-streams/)

Comment: I like where this is headed, but the second stream depends on the `documentID` of an item from the first stream. And the second stream is different for every item from the first. I need them to be nested in some manner rather than zipped