# How do I nest Streams in Dart (map Streams to Stream events)?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-async

Similar to [this Flutter question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57311479/6509751) I want to **nest** `Stream`s.
In Flutter, this can be achieved easily by nesting `StreamBuilder`s, however, I do not want to use widgets. Instead, I want to solve the problem in **Dart** alone. (nesting here means that one stream depends on the values from another stream and these should be combined)

Let me illustrate the problem:

```
Stream streamB(String a);

streamA: 'Hi' --- 'Hello' ---- 'Hey'
```

As you can see, I have a `streamA` that continuously emits events and a `streamB` that arises **from** the events that `streamA` emits. In a `streamC`, I want to be updated about *every event* from `streamB`.

### Regular stream mapping

If I had `valueB` instead of `streamB`, I could simply use `streamA.map((event) => valueB(event))`, however, [`Stream.map`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.1/dart-async/Stream/map.html) can only handle synchronous values.
There is also [`Stream.asyncMap`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.1/dart-async/Stream/asyncMap.html), however, that only works for `Future`s.
Then, there is *also* [`Stream.expand`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.1/dart-async/Stream/expand.html), but that works only for **synchronous** iterables.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### [`Stream.asyncExpand`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.1/dart-async/Stream/asyncExpand.html)

There is actually an [`Stream.asyncExpand` method](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.1/dart-async/Stream/asyncExpand.html):

```dart
streamC = streamA.asyncExpand((event) => streamB(event));
```

However, this has the problem that the result stream (`streamC`) will only move on to the next event in the source stream (`streamA`) if the sub stream (`streamB`) of the first event has closed. In the case of say Cloud Firestore, this will never work because the sub stream will not close.

#### [`Stream.concurrentAsyncExpand`](https://pub.dev/documentation/stream_transform/latest/stream_transform/Merge/concurrentAsyncExpand.html)

Luckily, there is the [`stream_transform` package](https://pub.dev/packages/stream_transform)!

```dart
streamC = streamA.concurrentAsyncExpand((event) => streamB(event));
```

This package provides a concurrent *async* expand functionality. This way, the result stream does not wait for the sub streams to close.

However, this has the downside that the previous sub streams are not automatically closed when a new event in the source stream is received.
Thus, this is also not useful for Cloud Firestore.

#### [`Stream.switchMap`](https://pub.dev/documentation/stream_transform/latest/stream_transform/Switch/switchMap.html)

Also from the `stream_transform` package:

```dart
streamC = streamA.switchMap((event) => streamB(event));
```

This solves the problem I outlined above.

Comment: The method 'sequentialAsyncExpand' does not resolve in the package you've linked.

Comment: @happyvirus Right, I corrected it. It is `switchMap`.

Comment: at the time of writing this comment `switchMap` function is available in the rxdart package as well and works as a charm