# Getting error as "Unhandled Exception: Bad state: failed to create store: 10001 Cannot open store: another store is still open using the same path"

Tags: flutter, objectbox, flutter-objectbox

The app is open then After clicking notification `main` gets called again and then getting `store` object as null but still getting this error when `await openStore()` is called

```
Unhandled Exception: Bad state: failed to create store: 10001 Cannot open store: another store is still open using the same path
```

```
static Future<Store> getStore() async{
    if(store != null) {
      print("StoreIsNotNull");
      return store!;
    }else{
      print("StoreIsNull");
      store = await openStore();
      return store!;
    }
  }
```

So when notification is clicked then store object is getting as null.

Comment: please include codes too

Comment: What package did you use? Is it [objectbox](https://pub.dev/packages/objectbox)?

Comment: yes @AlannMaulana

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same issue trying to open a store from a background task. The issue was resolved by using an already open store or create a new store if not yet opened.

```dart
if(Store.isOpen('directory-path')){
  // applicable when store is from other isolate
  return Store.attach(getObjectBoxModel(), 'directory-path');
}
return await openStore(directory: 'directory-path');
```

Comment: Followed this approach and it worked. Also a detailed discussion can be found here:
https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-dart/issues/436

Answer (score 0):

To avoid reopen store while it still already open, just use `Completer` :

```
import 'dart:async';

// global variable
final Completer<Store> _storeCompleter = Completer<Store>();

Future<void> initStore() async {
    if (!_storeCompleter.isCompleted) {
      final store = await openStore();
      _storeCompleter.complete(store); 
    }
}

Future<Store> getStore() async {
    return await _storeCompleter.future;
}

Future<void> main() async {
  // This is required so ObjectBox can get the application directory
  // to store the database in.
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  // initialize store
  await initStore();

  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Then, if you want to get `Person` box from store :

```
final store = await getStore();
final box = store.box<Person>();
final person = Person(firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe');
box.put(person);
```

So when `initStore` is not complete, the `getStore` will wait and would not return any store instance.

Comment: This is not working @Alann Maulana

Comment: I use this on almost all of my projects using `objectbox`. Maybe uploading some minimal reproducing code will be helpful to show how your app works. Sometimes code is ok, just because we put it on the wrong place it can cause error.

Comment: The problem is that on clicking notification new instance of main() is called and then store is getting created again since it was null but previous opened store wasnt closed so that is causing the error. If I call "DatabaseHelper.store?.close();" in notificationClickFunction then it helps but then I face "store is already closed" issue

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

use an async function, redo the code with an async function, if the function or command you wanted to do was done, it would move to next, instead of clicking on the notification that would become null and would stay there and it wouldn't close itself, that's kinda heavy for a program you should only allow executions it would have
like : -> open me -> one done opening closed -> then done

Answer (score 0):

Using **objectbox: ^2.0.0**

```
class ObjectBoxService {
  late final Store store;
  static ObjectBoxService? _instance;

  ObjectBoxService._create(this.store) {
    // Add any additional setup code, e.g. build queries.
  }

  static Future<ObjectBoxService> create() async {
    if (_instance != null) {
      return _instance!;
    } else {
      final docsDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
      final storePath = p.join(docsDir.path, "hestatistics");

      // Check if the store is already open
      if (Store.isOpen(storePath)) {
        // Attach to the already opened store
        final store = Store.attach(getObjectBoxModel(),storePath);
        _instance = ObjectBoxService._create(store);
      } else {
        // Future<Store> openStore() {...} is defined in the generated objectbox.g.dart
        final store = await openStore(directory: storePath);
        _instance = ObjectBoxService._create(store);
      }
      return _instance!;
    }
  }
}
```